# Problem with pytube for playing music on discord by link

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pytube

hello i'm creating a discord bot, not a big deal just for personal use i used for weeks and all things work just fine but an issue as raised i think this line is the problem:

```
audio_url = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().url
```

I re-read the official documentation but I can't find anything, maybe the problem itself is discord, here is the full code of the function for play music:

```
async def play_mus(ctx, url):
    try:
        video = YouTube(url)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error: Link not valid.")
        return
   
    audio_url = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().url
   
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("must be in a vc.")
        return
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()    
    voice_client.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_url))  
    await ctx.send(f"now playing: {video.title}.")
```

i tried to read the official pytube documentation, i tried to update the libraries, i tried to change the code but they always gave an error, everything stops before a certain line of code trying to change that the problem remains, so i don't know how to fix it.